# c# лагает программа при прорисовке

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть программа по типу игры лабиринта, реализована в windows forms. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы не весь лабиринт был виден сразу (как на рисунке). Был написан код, чтобы было видно только часть, а остальная была покрыта чёрной областью. Но при перемещении мыши программа сильно лагает (другие её элементы). Для буферизации свойству формы DoubleBuffered прописал значение true. Подскажите, как нужно изменить код чтобы избежать лагов, спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)  // этот участок отвечает за черный круг
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        SetEventHandlers(this);
    }
    private void SetEventHandlers(Control ct)
    {
        ct.Paint += PaintControl;
        ct.MouseMove += (o, e) => Invalidate(true);
        foreach (Control item in ct.Controls)
        {
            SetEventHandlers(item);
        }
    }

    int Radius = 100;

    void PaintControl(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //context = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
        //bufer = context.Allocate(Graphics, Form.DisplayRectangle);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;

        Control ct = (Control)sender;
        Point ct_position = ct.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        Point client_position = this.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
        int shiftX = ct_position.X - client_position.X;
        int shiftY = ct_position.Y - client_position.Y;
        Point p = PointToClient(MousePosition);
        p.Offset(-shiftX, -shiftY);
        using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            path.AddRectangle(new Rectangle(-shiftX, -shiftY, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height));
            path.AddEllipse(p.X - Radius, p.Y - Radius, 2 * Radius, 2 * Radius);
            e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Black, path);  // этот участок отвечает за черный круг

        }
    }
```

Comment: Как вариант решения - отрисовать картинку 1 раз в память, далее рисовать чёрный фон на форме, и по верх него, в нужном месте, рисовать фрагмент картинки из памяти.

Comment: У вас же, рекурсивно перерисовывается куча других компонентов (зачем?), вместо того чтобы рисовать всё на одном полотне...

Comment: Немного не понял, как рисовать на одном полотне. Только начинаю знакомство с языком, не подскажите, как перерисовывать только нужную мне область? Спасибо!

Comment: у вас есть форма. У формы есть полотно с графикой. Вам достаточно рисовать на нём всё самому, и не надо заставлять другие компоненты, находящиеся на форме, рисоваться на этой форме. Вы добавляете очередной метод рисования, который срабатывает самым последним, а достаточно затереть родительский метод. Если сцена вашей игры статична - рисовать её надо 1 раз, в момент загрузки этой сцены. Если сцена динамична - рисовать её надо только в тот момент когда в сцене что то меняется (например, убирается стена, или дверь, и т.д.). После отрисовки картинка-результат сохраняется.

Comment: В общем, это обычная оптимизация. Сейчас у вас куча ненужных операций, от которых надо избавиться. Когда вы уберёте свои линии, столкнётесь ещё с тем, что вам надо где то хранить схемы коллизий (ваши стены), но, если у вас всё сделано грамотно, ничего принципиально нового делать не придётся

Comment: Спасибо за подробное разъяснение, буду стараться всё оптимизировать!